# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. error

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

This error displays in the console whenever I try to build flutter apk.

Below is the error:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.  Could not find
>   method classpath() for arguments
>   [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Even on a new created project?

Comment: working fine after creating a new project

Comment: can you help me in solving this error  `Note: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlan
g.org\url_launcher-5.1.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.`

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not provided your `build.gradle`, try to apply this in `build.gradle`(Project: your project name) where `tools.build:gradle` is present and not in `build.gradle`(Module: app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.5.1'
    }
}
```

In `build.gradle`(Module: app) outside dependencies add this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Hey I'm a Flutter Dev and in ``` build.gradle ```` line 26 throws a build exception. How can I fix that